# SQL*Plus - How do you hide SET ECHO OFF?

Tags: oracle, set, echo, sqlplus

In SQL PLus, if I want to hide the command on screen, I use at the beginning of the script:

```
SET ECHO OFF
```

But what about this command? How to hide also this?

In MS-Dos you could use @ in front of it, but in SQL*Plus?

EDIT:
I know the -S option for SQL*Plus, but the problem is that I am sending my script to the client and therefore I don't control how they are running SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to start SQL*Plus with the `-S` flag:

```
sqlplus -S user/password@db @path/to/your/script
```

---

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169506) says: **SILENT Option**

-S[ILENT]

Suppresses all SQL*Plus information and prompt messages, including the command prompt, the echoing of commands, and the banner normally displayed when you start SQL*Plus. If you omit username or password, SQL*Plus prompts for them, but the prompts are not visible! Use SILENT to invoke SQL*Plus within another program so that the use of SQL*Plus is invisible to the user.

SILENT is a useful mode for creating reports for the web using the SQLPLUS -MARKUP command inside a CGI script or operating system script. The SQL*Plus banner and prompts are suppressed and do not appear in reports created using the SILENT option.SILENT Option

---

So, with the silent option it seems that there won't be need to use `set echo` at all.

Comment: I already knew this option. But the problem is that I am sending my script to the client and therefore I don't control how they are running SQL*Plus.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is of course an important piece of information that merrits being added to the question.

Answer (score 4):

No, I know of no way to hide the 'set echo off' command itself, if echo is on.

However, echo is off by default.  So, if echo is on when you initially start SQL*Plus, perhaps you have a login.sql or glogin.sql that contains 'set echo on'?

Check for glogin.sql in $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin, and for login.sql in the directory where you started SQL*Plus and any directory listed in $SQLPATH.

Hope that helps.